# Chrome viewer pdf button not working with jsPDF

Tags: pdf, jspdf

[Chrome pdf viewer button is not working with jsPDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsdYz.png)

I am using jsPDF to generate pdf and it works fine. Chrome viewer pdf button is not working. I have tried number of different methods but I didn't get success.

Here I would like to share sample code:

```
download() {
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

// Save the PDF

var string = doc.output('datauristring');
var iframe = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + string + "'></iframe>"
var x = window.open();
x.document.open();
x.document.write(iframe);
x.document.close();
//doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

}

through this code, new tab is open and but chrome viewer download button is not working.

So is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the solution. We have to simply use this code and Chrome pdf viewer download buttons works fine.

window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank');

Comment: not working for me, can you please specify where did you used window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank');??

Comment: @SergioCano at the end of your pdf file code your can user this code and pdf open in new tab and you have option to download the file as such: window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank');

Comment: thanks, it is working, but it is also generating other problem, the pdfs name is now the url of the new tab opened, which is a very rare name, how did you handle it? thanks in advance

Comment: I used this function doc.save('fileName' );   before window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank'); When user click on it, then it will give option to Save the file with your specified fileName. But unfortunately I didn't got solution to change the name of file  when User click on Download button through Browser.

Comment: ok thank you for your help! if i find any solution i will share it :)

Comment: @SergioCano Did you ever find a fix? I've run into the same problem, but Bradhen's fix, did not fix it for me.
For me it just opens and closes the new window.

Comment: @Carsten Sorry mate, i couldn't find a solution, but i found an alternative method... showing the PDF in a modal, so i dont need to open a new tab... so... the pdf's name and download button is working all fine. hope it helps you

Comment: @Carsten, I think you are using adblocker. You have also allow download option in chrome setting.

Answer (score 0):

Although `window.open` works fine, for security reasons new chrome versions are blocking by default the popup and hence I've needed another solution.

I would personally had another try for the iframe solution. I am writing the solution that worked for me below:

HTML code (for full size iframe on the screen):

```
 <iframe id="main-iframe" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2; border: none;"></iframe>
```

JavaScript code:

```
 document.getElementById('main-iframe').setAttribute('src', doc.output('bloburl'));
```

Answer (score 0):

A few handy things to add:
window.open worked for me, however when I only used

```
window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'), '_blank')
```

it gave me the error of

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'URL' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

to correct this all I had to add was .toString(). Below is the code I used and also how to edit the title of the tab that opens up.

```
PDF.setProperties({
    title: "jsPDF sample"
});
window.open(PDF.output('bloburl').toString(), '_blank');
```